# Cordova's css not supported in old Android Versions?

Tags: css, html, cordova

I am using the latest version of cordova to compile HTML5 app, there are elements like `flex` :
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
and also `background: linear-gradient` which are not supported.

I've tried them on on API 20(4.4) and anything below, they show up funny and broken, why is that, and is there a fix for that?

Comment: They switched webview to be chromium-based (chrome v. 33) in android kitkat 4.4. The old webview pre-4.4 uses the old flexbox model, detailed here: https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-flexbox-20090723

Comment: https://benfrain.com/flexbox-gotchas-for-android-2-1-4-3-stock-browser -- here is a good writeup of what you will need to change to have it work pre-4.4